# Using principle of inclusion-exclusion to solve for number of possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Of n containers and n objects, each container is assigned a "right" object and each container can hold no less or more than one object (no empty containers). How many possible combinations are there of containers and objects of size n where each container contains an object, but no container contains the "right" object?**

The possible number of combinations of at least k containers of n total containers containing the right object is $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}(n-k)!$, where $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}$ is the number of unique combinations of selected object of at least k objects in the correct container of n containers. $(n-k)!$ is the number of unique combinations of remaining containers of each one of the unique combinations.

(example n = 4, k = 1) $\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}(4-1)! = 4(6) = 24$ 
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{A}BCD & A\textbf{B}CD & AB\textbf{C}D & ABC\textbf{D} \\ 
\hline
\textbf{A}BDC & A\textbf{B}DC & AD\textbf{C}B & ACB\textbf{D} \\ 
\hline
\textbf{A}CBD & C\textbf{B}AD & BA\textbf{C}D & BAC\textbf{D} \\ 
\hline
\textbf{A}CDB & C\textbf{B}DA & BD\textbf{C}A & BCA\textbf{D} \\ 
\hline
\textbf{A}DBC & D\textbf{B}AC & DA\textbf{C}B & CAB\textbf{D} \\ 
\hline
\textbf{A}DCB & D\textbf{B}CA & DB\textbf{C}A &  CBA\textbf{D}\\ 
\hline
 \end{array}
$$

Principle of inclusion/exclusion
$$|\bar{A}_1 \bigcap \bar{A}_2\bigcap ... \bar{A}_n\bigcap| = |\mathcal{U}| - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |A_i| + \sum\limits_{i \neq j}^n |A_i \bigcap A_j|+...+(-1)^n|A_1\bigcap A_2\bigcap ... A_m|$$

Apply principle of inclusion/exclusion(PIE) with formula for possible combinations of n containers of k object in correct container: $(-1)^k\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}(n-k)!$

$$D_n = n! - \begin{pmatrix} n \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}(n-1)! + \begin{pmatrix} n \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}(n-2)! - \begin{pmatrix} n \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}(n-3)! + . . . . .  + (-1)^k\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}(n-k)! + . . .  + (-1)^n\begin{pmatrix} n \\ n \end{pmatrix}(n-n)!
= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}(n-k)!$$

Replace binomial coefficient with $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$
$$D_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \begin{pmatrix} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\end{pmatrix}(n-k)!$$

Reduce fraction.
$$D_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \begin{pmatrix} \frac{n!}{k!}\end{pmatrix}$$
Since n! is a constant, it can be removed from sum and placed out front.
$$D_n = n! \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{k!}\end{pmatrix}$$

Substitute $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{-1^k}{k!}$ with $e^-1$

$$D_n = n! e^{-1} = \frac{n!}{e}$$

**D_n needs to be an integer instead of a rational number. Any ideas? Maybe estimating an alternating series theorem could be applied here?**

Comment: You can't substitute $e^{-1}$ for that finite sum – why would you think such a thing would be possible? It gives a good *estimate*, but if you're after the exact answer, it's strictly a no-no.

Comment: that's what I was wondering is how to create a function that would work using an approximation.

Comment: So you want it to be a good approximation, and an integer? You wouldn't settle for $[n!/e]$, where $[x]$ is the greatest-integer function, would you?

Comment: I've been plugging away at this and it seems like a floor function would work where it evaluates [n!/e + 1/2]

Comment: Yes, $[x+(1/2)]$ gives the integer nearest to $x$.